# Using Ajax in the existing php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to php and trying to make my own chat web app. The app is working except the fact that i have to manually refresh the page in order to get the new messages from the 2nd party. I found that using ajax is the simplest way to do that. can someone guide me through the process of inserting ajax? Here is the php script i want to edit.

```
$msg="SELECT sender, message, recvr, time FROM message WHERE sender=('$sender' OR '$recvr') AND recvr=('$recvr' OR '$sender') ORDER BY time";  

$run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$msg);  

while ($t = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {

              if ("$t[sender]"==$sender && "$t[recvr]"==$recvr) {

                echo"<div style='text-align:right;padding-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px;width:auto;'>";
                echo    "<h14>$t[message]&nbsp;&nbsp;" ;
                echo date("G:i/M j", strtotime("$t[time]"));
                  echo   "</h14> </div>";
              }
              if("$t[sender]"==$recvr &&  "$t[recvr]"==$sender){
                echo    "<div style=' margin-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
                echo    "<h15>$t[message]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" ;
                echo date("G:i/M j", strtotime("$t[time]"));
                  echo   " </h15></div>";
              }

} 
 echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this but I can at least give pointers as to how I would do this.

1) The PHP code you currently have can be placed into a file on it's own.

2) Include JQuery(because it is easier than raw AJAX) and look into $.post()/$.get() functions. These will allow you to use javascript to pull a response from a php page.

3) Javascript has two functions, setTimeout() setInterval() which will allow you to run the javascript function, which pulls this data, periodically.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You may use JQuery, here's the refrence: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Before you can use JQuery library you should put the CDN which you can find it here http://jquery.com/download/, put that on the header of your html.

Here is an example on how to use ajax:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#send').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "example.com/sender.php",
      data: {"sender": "John", "receiver": "Doe"}
     });
    });
   });
</script>
```

On your php file you can get the data by $_POST. You can check the ajax request by using inspect element or firebug then go to network, then check the headers form data.